# Confused about arrays in C

Tags: c

Hey guys I am learning the basics of C language and I am a little bit confused about how to use arrays.

I mean what are they used for?

Comment: This should be on stackoverflow since this is not related to gamedev.

Comment: I would recommend to you first learn how to use the language (C or C++… your choice) before attempting to develop a game, on your first question you asked about a basic 2D game, but if you don't know how to use the language, then that will be almost impossible to do at the moment

Comment: Sorry...I was too excited about developing.

Answer (score 2):

Ever made a shopping list?

That's an array of type `std::string[]`.  Or if you want to get really technical, it could be considered an array of type `ItemConsumable[]` (because "Steve" is a valid string, but you certainly can't buy him!)

In game programming, you would just arrays (or lists) to keep track of objects, actions, events, or other data.  It entirely depends on the use.  You might even have a (two dimensional!) array that your units use for pathfinding.

Comment: `String` must be `std::string`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You would be correct.  I don't work in C so my syntax and proper declarations are more than rusty, but examples are valid no matter what language.

Comment: That's ok, answer and examples are good. I just decided to tell it to you instead of editing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Just edit it, dude, I won't be offended. :) I've accepted a couple of edits where the editor was *more correct* than I had been (variable naming, for instance), or for minor things like syntax errors or spelling.  Comments just makes me think, "FFS, just edit it yourself."

Answer (score -1):

First of all. C is not the same as C++. (They are different programming languages)

Now, (trying to explain without making it too complicated), arrays are lists of variables.

[image]

**(The image has Numbers with capital letters, my fail, ignore that, shouldn´t have the starting letter in capitals)**

For example, `int numbers[10];` is an array that contains space for 10 ints (numbers).

You can access values from the array ("list"):

```
exampleIntVariable = numbers[1];
```

Our variable will have the value of the **2ND** number in our list **(The first one is numbers[0])**